# Erlang: Node freezes totaly. Now what?

Tags: erlang

Platform: windows 7 32bit, erlang R15B01.

I have developed an erlang server that simultaneously listens to 200 different tcp ports (200 gen_servers)

After a few minutes of moderate load(few clients in parallel) the entire node just freezes completely - even the shell freezes entirely.

How can this problem get diagnosed? is there a standard erlang  approach for those kind of problems? (memory consumption was low ,so its not some kind of memory leak)

**Important Edit**

It seems that under **werl.exe** there is no such problem. only under **erl.exe**. Probably same as in http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/erl-exe-dies-but-werl-exe-does-not-on-both-Windows-XP-and-2008R2-with-R14B01-td3335030.html

Comment: i suggest that you show us more of your code

Answer (score 7):

If you kill your process with `kill -SIGUSR1 <pid>`, the erlang VM will generate a erlang crash dump file `erl_crash.dump` in the directory the app was started.

Then you can analyze it using the [crash dump viewer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/crashdump_ug.html).

Comment: right. but this is a start. i could use also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672572/how-can-i-configure-windows-to-generate-a-core-dump-from-an-application

Comment: This problem only happens in windows. How can I force a dump file under windows? I tried using procdump but it creates a non-erlang dump that the viewer does not understand

Comment: Maybe you can go to Task Manager and kill the VM.

Comment: @Ethan. The problem is that erlang stops working. killing it using TM is easy

Comment: Is the erlang VM completely frozen? If not, you can force a crash using the shell: erlang:halt("crash").

Comment: The equivalent command under Windows is `taskkill` (that is, `taskkill /PID <pid>`).  Not sure whether that will allow Erlang to generate a crash dump, though.

Answer (score 0):

A frozen erlang shell can be caused by uncaught exit signals. You can try to trap exits in the shell process (assuming it is the parent process of your server) which should give you the exit reason. See [Reference manual on Errors](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#errors)

Comment: Tried that. It didn't make any difference

Comment: did you check the memory usage? maybe the VM runs out of memory.